# Heroku No Contexts defined

Tags: java, logging, heroku, jetty

I have a deployed application in heroku and I am unable to access it

**Heroku logs**

```
2015-10-18T14:13:28.456831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-10-18T14:13:38.538928+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2015-10-18T14:13:38.552255+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx384m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140316+00:00 app[web.1]: 2015-10-18 14:13:39.135:INFO:oejr.Runner:main: Runner
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140320+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR: No Contexts defined
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140321+00:00 app[web.1]: Usage: java [-Djetty.home=dir] -jar jetty-runner.jar [--help|--version] [ server opts] [[ context opts] context ...] 
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140322+00:00 app[web.1]: Server opts:
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140323+00:00 app[web.1]:  --version                           - display version and exit
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140324+00:00 app[web.1]:  --log file                          - request log filename (with optional 'yyyy_mm_dd' wildcard
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140325+00:00 app[web.1]:  --out file                          - info/warn/debug log filename (with optional 'yyyy_mm_dd' wildcard
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140326+00:00 app[web.1]:  --host name|ip                      - interface to listen on (default is all interfaces)
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140327+00:00 app[web.1]:  --port n                            - port to listen on (default 8080)
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140328+00:00 app[web.1]:  --stop-port n                       - port to listen for stop command
2015-10-18T14:13:39.130872+00:00 app[web.1]: 2015-10-18 14:13:39.127:INFO::main: Logging initialized @89ms
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140329+00:00 app[web.1]:  --stop-key n                        - security string for stop command (required if --stop-port is present)
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140329+00:00 app[web.1]:  [--jar file]*n                      - each tuple specifies an extra jar to be added to the classloader
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140330+00:00 app[web.1]:  [--lib dir]*n                       - each tuple specifies an extra directory of jars to be added to the classloader
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140331+00:00 app[web.1]:  [--classes dir]*n                   - each tuple specifies an extra directory of classes to be added to the classloader
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140332+00:00 app[web.1]:  --stats [unsecure|realm.properties] - enable stats gathering servlet context
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140332+00:00 app[web.1]:  [--config file]*n                   - each tuple specifies the name of a jetty xml config file to apply (in the order defined)
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140333+00:00 app[web.1]: Context opts:
2015-10-18T14:13:39.140334+00:00 app[web.1]:  [[--path /path] context]*n          - WAR file, web app dir or context xml file, optionally with a context path
2015-10-18T14:13:39.939608+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-10-18T14:13:39.957993+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**Foreman start**

```
11:29:04 web.1  | started with pid 464
11:29:04 web.1  | Error: Unable to access jarfile target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar
11:29:04 web.1  | exited with code 1
11:29:04 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

**Pom.xml file**

```
<configuration>
    <artifactItems>
        <artifactItem>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
            <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
        </artifactItem>
    </artifactItems>
</configuration>
```

Every time I try to access my application displays the following message by the browser

[image]

Because I am unable to access my application? Did any compatibility error with the jetty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you deploying you app? With a `git push`, `mvn heroku:deploy`, `heroku deploy:war`, something else?

Your `pom.xml` should include all of this around the jetty-runner config:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
            <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                        <version>9.2.7.v20150116</version>
                        <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

That is, make sure it's bound to the `package` goal. If you are using `git push`, then check the build output to make sure that plugin config runs.

Finally, check that jetty-runner exists by inspecting the slug:

```
$ heroku run ls target/dependency
```

Comment: Hello codefinger, thank you so much for your help and explanation. I managed to solve the problem and is working normally.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem of deploy to Heroku. To format my pom.xml file with the CTRL + SHIFT + F shortcut in eclipse my code was as follows:

**Problem**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <appName>cliente-mws-usp</appName>
        <processTypes>
            <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar
                --port $PORT target/*.war</web>
        </processTypes>
        <stack>cedar-14</stack>
        <jdkVersion>1.7</jdkVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The problem was that Heroku performed only stretch `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar` and regarded the rest of the command `--port $PORT target/*.war` for I have broken the line. To undo the formatting and leave all the command on only one line deploy again function normally.

**Solution**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <appName>cliente-mws-usp</appName>
        <processTypes>
            <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war</web>
        </processTypes>
        <stack>cedar-14</stack>
        <jdkVersion>1.7</jdkVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Once again thank you so much for your help and explanation.